Wood-eating bug in Germany
This bug was found in an old church in Southern Germany. Apparently it was damaging/eating wood. A local woodworker could not identify the bug and speculated that it was some foreign species.
Unfortunately I only have these blurry pictures, but I figured that it is worth a shot.


UPDATE: A specialist who was consulted by the church where the bug was found believed the bug to be Lyctus brunneus (brown powderpost beetle), but did not provide rationale.

It is usually the larvae of beetles that are the wood damaging ones, not to say there aren't beetles that might chew on wood, but the ones that do don't tend to cause a lot of damage.
